# Code in Powerpoint presentation

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, javascript, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

I am putting together a powerpoint presentation which will contain some JavaScript samples.
Just wondering what tips anyone has to make this easy to read?  I am specifically looking for tips on fonts, layout etc.
Many thanks

Comment: The less code the better.

Answer (score 6):

Having given more than my fair share of presentations for developers, I can tell you one thing--never, ever, put any real code into a Powerpoint Presentation!

First, ask yourself if people will benefit from seeing code snippits on a PPT; will they remember it?  Will they write it down?  Can the audience use the code based entirely on its usage on the page?  If you're using code to demonstrate a specific feature of the presentation, don't let it go over more than a few lines.  If its an example, make sure that same example is available (fleshed out) in the documentation or similar.

Second, only use code when it serves to demonstrate a purpose.  If you're giving a presentation about recursive functions, for example, it makes perfect sense to include things like a basic example.  However, before writing it in your code of choice, consider this: wouldn't it be easier to include *pseudocode* instead?  Not only is it easier to read, but you can reach more people because it no longer relies on their knowledge of a language.

Finally, if you absolutely do need to include code in your presentation, put it in an application designed for it.  I highly recommend an online code review linked from the presentation--that way, when you want to display it, you can click on the link and get:

1. An entire code base that any of your audience members can check out and use.
2. Syntax highlighting and line numbering!
3. Centralized location that anybody can return to, without having to navigate through an unfamiliar source tree, etc..

Just my two cents, and I wish you luck on your future presentations!

Answer (score 1):

If it is a simple presentation, just type the code into Visual Studios.  It will automatically color the syntax to where you can copy and paste it into Powerpoint.  I do this all the time with Word.

Answer (score -1):

microsoft has made working with office easy

insert all your slides you want in your presentation
populate them with data 
then what you can do is at the top of pp window click design
then from design pp will populate a list of designs you can use for your presentation
each design has its own layout, background color, font color, etc
this design will apply to all your slides

Comment: He's asking specifically about code. Unless one of those themes uses a monospace font, among other things, this won't help.